# Spring boot in docker does not see classes annotated with profile

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

I have some classes that supposed to be initialized only on production environment, thus i have added profile annotations to them.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/authenticate")
@Profile(value = {"development", "production"})
public class AuthenticationController
```

And in the application.properties file, i'm setting it as:

```
spring.profiles.active=production
```

This approach works for me on outside of the container, but in docker, i see these classes are not initializing even I'm setting the right profile on docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  web:
    image: johndoe/readingisgood
    build: .
    environment:
      - "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=production"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    command: --spring.profiles.active=production
    depends_on:
      - MongoDB
```

And even i see the following message on the logs of the container.

```
The following 1 profile is active: "production"
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk:11
ARG JAR_FILE=target/ReadingIsGood-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your command should be -Dspring.profiles.active=production

Comment: Can you share your dockerfile?

Comment: @SergioSantiago shared it.

Comment: @SergioSantiago it's very embarassing. i wasn't building the new image at all. it is resolved when i do docker-compose up --build

Comment: No problem, happy you fixed